# MLflow unfinished experiment saved as finished

Tags: python, mlflow

when I create a run using `mlflow.start_run()` ,even if my script is interrupted before executing `mlflow.end_run()`, the run gets tagged as finished instead of unfinished in Status?

Comment: I have experienced a similar issue on version 1.14.1 . Which version are you using? Are you executing this from a notebook?

Comment: I am using 1.13.1 and this is happening in both notebooks and .py files. Were you able to fix the problem in some other version @WaterKnight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your notebook stops the run gets the status finished. However, if you want to continue logging metrics or artifacts to that run, you just need to use `mlflow.start_run(run_id="YourRunIDYouCanGetItFromUI")`. This is explained in the [documentation](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.html#mlflow.start_run)